# Tensorflow dataset API slow to get data on large batch size

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I find that getting one batch from tensorflow dataset API can be super slow when the batch size is large even when all data is in memory. Following is one example. Does anyone have any insight ?

```
FEATURE_NUM = 500
tf_X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, FEATURE_NUM], name="X")
tf_Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name="Y")

batch_size = 1000000
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf_X, tf_Y)).batch(batch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

se = tf.Session()
se.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
se.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={tf_X : numpy_array_X, tf_Y : numpy_array_Y})

while True:
    data = se.run(next_element) # This takes more than 5 seconds per call
```